# git: Trying to re-create same repo but with some different files

Tags: git, version-control, github

so I re-installed my OS, and now I am facing a git dilemma.

I have an existing git repo on the web which has some things I have changed specifically because they weren't working with my server yadda yadda etc etc..

I now have a very similar repo but with quite a few core changes, here's what I need to know how to do:

I want to re-initialize the repo to use my new folder but yet overwrite the different files on the server.  My folder has no .git in it, so I will need to make one, but how do I overwrite my changes on to an existing git repo online?

Is it close to git push --force??  but how would I init the same repo into this folder without cloning (something I don't want to do since I don't want to overwrite my changes)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural thing (for me at least) to do here is to have these modifications in a new commit, keeping history of your project. There's no need to push --force!

To do so, you must first clone your repo back to the local machine, but in a different directory so that it doesn't overwrite.

```
git clone git://myrepo.com clonedrepo
```

Then copy the "working copy" in your local repo:

```
cp -r workingdir clonedrepo
```

If you have deleted files in workingdir, you'll have to delete them by hand on the destination directory. Finally stage and commit:

```
git add . && git commit -m "details on what changed"
```

You'll be able to push normally since no history was rewritten.

Comment: since git works with states, one simpler way to do that is to copy the .git of the old repo in the new directory and then commit all the results. Et voila !

Comment: Also thought about it but if the OP isn't familiar with git it sounds hacky. But yes it's more straightforward.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I wasn't sure if just moving the .git or the whole folder over would allow it to detect the changes since it did seem 'hackish' at the time.